# postgresql full text search behaviour in case of double quotes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want string wrapped in double quotes or single quotes to be searched exactly, but I am getting unpredictable behavior when using double quotes in search query.

Like when I am searching this,

```
fusion=# select to_tsquery('simple','"data|" & "%center"');

    to_tsquery    
------------------
 'data' | 'center'
```

But, when I am searching, this

```
fusion=# select to_tsquery('simple','"data\|" & "%center"');

 to_tsquery    
------------------
 'data' & 'center'
```

There are no guidelines in official documentation regarding behavior when using quotes.

Please explain, thanks in advance.

Comment: fts works with lexemes, not phrases - no?

Comment: Postgresql 9.6 search for phrases, but I am using 9.3 currently.

Comment: so you can do it in several steps then - right?.. first effective fts for lexemmes and then on result operator `LIKE` with exact phrase

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in several steps - first effective fts for lexemes on accordingly indexed attribute and then on result do operator `LIKE` with exact phrase:

```
t=# select version();
                                                   version
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.3.14 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit
(1 row)

t=# with t(v) as (values('the center of the data'),('the center of the database'),('data| %center'))
, filter as (select v,v@@ to_tsquery('simple','data & center') fts from t)
select *,v like '%data|%' and v like e'%\%center%' exact_words from filter;
             v              | fts | exact_words
----------------------------+-----+-------------
 the center of the data     | t   | f
 the center of the database | f   | f
 data| %center              | t   | t
(3 rows)
```

so then smth like:

```
t=# with t(v) as (values('the center of the data'),('the center of the database'),('data| %center'))
, filter as (select v,v@@ to_tsquery('simple','data & center') fts from t)
select v from filter where fts and v like '%data|%' and v like e'%\%center%';
       v
---------------
 data| %center
(1 row)
```